# Where can I find release notes for Yosemite beta releases

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program

I'm enrolled to receive OSX Yosemite beta update (AFTER the official release of Yosemite). I installed OS X 10.10.1 (14B17) without problems and now have IB423 available in the app store. I would like to view a list of changes / release notes relating to the build. Is this available somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't available. Most likely you can find is the seed notes you could find out in the [developers website](https://developer.apple.com) → Member Center → Mac.

[image]

Comment: thanks. Where is that screenshot from? Do you need to be a registered and paid Mac developer to see the seed notes then? I do have a developer account (IOS) but it has lapsed.

Comment: Yes, you need a registered paid Mac Developer account. With iOS Developer account (lapsed or not) you can't see it. BTW, there is not much information on this notes, you can see something similar on the App Store update description.